# Can naxcel and metronidazole be administered simultaneously?

Tags: dogs, medicines, diseases

Vet today gave our dog 1 injection of Naxcel and prescribed Metronidazol.
Can I start giving Metronidazol today or should I wait until tomorrow?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a vet and it is always important to ask your vet, but both drugs are antibiotic treatments. Normally Naxcel would be administered over a course of many days with daily injections, but can only be administered by a vet. Based on that, it would seem reasonable to presume that if you're not slated for another visit to your vet tomorrow, that the Metronidazol is the carry-on medication and should be administered starting tomorrow for the duration proscribed by the vet.

Sorry to repeat, but this is important, I'm not a vet and I would suggest a call to your vet or an emergency vet clinic to confirm my take on it is wise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Veterinary was closed at that time, that's why I asked.
P.S. vet didn't prescribed a course of naxcel daily injections, just an antibiotic.